# How to pull data from a different list with additional validations?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, sharepoint-list

I am fairly new to Sharepoint and InfoPath Designer integration. The reason, why I am using InfoPath, is because I do not have the access rights to use Sharepoint designer here.

So I am hoping to get your thoughts on how to go about with my dilemma. Please note that I am not a coder as well.

I have 2 lists, Master List, and Tracker List. Master List contains the core information of the client. Tracker list SHOULD contain basic information of clients and the updates made by the support.

[image]

Now here's the problem, on my tracker list, I want the Submitter Name field be auto-populated once the TSOID, TAXID and SUBMITTER ID has been placed. Which means that the TSOID, TAXID, and SUBMITTERID should reference correctly from the master-list.

[image]

So for example, if I am the support, I'll open the list tracker, plug in the TSOID(z999), TAXID(900000001), and submitter(910000001) ID and automatically the submitter name will be populated based on the correct information validated from the masterlist. If one of the 3 is incorrect, the Submitter name field will not be populated.

**p.s. I am Office 365 and InfoPath 2013**

Answer (score 0):

So what I did here is, to use InfoPath's rules.
Experimented for a while until I was able to get my expected result.